# Declaring a string returning function in a header file. Conflicting Types?

Tags: c, function, declaration

I have this in my header file:

```
const char * keyBoard();
```

And in one of my C files the function is this:

```
const char * keyboard() 
{
     //mycode
     return string;
}
```

I get this error with my compiler:

```
 error: conflicting types for 'keyBoard'  
 const char * keyBoard(char hintTxt[30], int maxNumbers, bool multiLine)  
....................^~~~~~~~  
note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration  
 {  
 ^  
(in header file) note: previous declaration of 'keyBoard' was here  
 const char * keyBoard();  
....................^~~~~~~~
```

I don't care about the middle part because I don't know if it matters right now, but what is with the whole "conflicting types for 'keyBoard'" crap? They are the exact same as far as I can tell, and I can't find any help on this topic

Comment: `what is with the whole "conflicting types for 'keyBoard'" crap`..it's the _crap_ because of your code, dont blame the compiler.

Comment: the error message doesn't match your code

Comment: @FelixPalmen or rather, the code _shown_ here.

Comment: BTW - `keyBoard` != `keyboard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, your function is defined as:

```
const char * keyBoard(char hintTxt[30], int maxNumbers, bool multiLine)
```

But you declare it as:

```
const char * keyBoard();
```

These don't match.  The declaration has to match the definition:

```
const char * keyBoard(char hintTxt[30], int maxNumbers, bool multiLine);
```

Comment: In my header file I also have functions like this:
int games();
int tools();
but in the rest of the code they are:
int games(char userDir[30])
and
int tools(char userDir[30])
why do those ones work without matching the definition

Comment: They do not match either, but because they only have one parameter compiler  complains slightly less. Turn up the warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall` and you will get plenty.

Answer (score 2):

You declared the function without its prototype that is the number and types of parameters are unknown

```
const char * keyBoard();
```

In this case when the function is called the compiler performs the so-called *default argument promotions*.
And the error message means the following (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>   double. **These are called the default argument promotions**....

You should declare the function specifying its parameters before to call it.

```
const char * keyBoard(char hintTxt[30], int maxNumbers, bool multiLine);
```

Take into account that a declaration does not need to match the function definition. You may declare a function without its parameters. But in this case you have to take into account the *default argument promotions*.